# How to fetch multiple rows in PHP array with json_encode()?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a simple search form using PHP/MySql. The issue I am stuck with is I am able to fetch one field from the database and not the second field, i.e, if I pass only first_name in the array, but as soon as I pass the last_name field, it shows up 'undefined' in the search box.

I know I am doing something wrong somewhere which I am not able to get into. Any help on how to get both the variables together would be greatly appreciated since I need both the first and last name to be displayed. Thanks

Here is my code

**index.php**

```
<?php
    include('db.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <script src="typeahead.min.js"></script>

      <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
            name: 'typeahead',
            remote:'search_bootstrap.php?key=%QUERY',
            limit : 10
        });
    });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" style="width: 200px;" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type a name">
</body>
</html>
```

**search_bootstrap.php**

```
<?php
    $key=$_GET['key'];
    $array = array();
    $con=mysql_connect("host","user","password");
    $db=mysql_select_db("user",$con);
    $query=mysql_query("select * from registered_users where first_name LIKE '%{$key}%'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $firstName = $row['first_name'];
        $lastName = $row['last_name'];

      array_push($array , array("first"=>$firstName, "last"=>$lastName));
    }
    echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Comment: you should use JSON.parse()

Comment: you mean JSON.parse($array)? I tried that, doesn't work, if that is what you mean.

Comment: `$lastName = $row['last_name'];];` should be`$lastName = $row['last_name'];`

Comment: my bad, just edited it above. I am still getting undefined in the search box, whereas if I go to search_bootstrap.php individually, all the results are there in the array.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because you have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) here.

Comment: yep, I will be moving onto mysqli sooner, but first I need to get this thing sorted out

Comment: search_bootstrap.php returns the results in an array, but the searchbox shows an undefined error.